# Spark is unable to read Hive ORC table having data files with different version of schema

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, orc

I have a hive ORC partitioned table created as below.

```
create table default.tab_xyz (
wid String,
update_at timestamp,
type String,
id long)
 PARTITIONED BY (                                                                      
   minorversion string)                           
 ROW FORMAT SERDE                                   
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'      
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'  
 OUTPUTFORMAT                                       
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
```

Now under the partition there are two versions 2.1 and 2.2. When i have taken schema from version files it is like below.

*** 2.1 Version Schema ***

```
wid : String,
type: String,
update_at : timestamp
```

*** 2.2 Version Schema ***

```
wid : String,
update_at : timestamp,
type: String,
id : long
```

When i execute the 
`select * from default.tab_xyz` in hive it works fine.

But when i do 
`spark.sql("select * from default.tab_xyz")` it throws me below error 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.orc.mapred.OrcTimestamp` because for 2.1 version file it mapping 
`type` column with 
`update_at` column in table.

is there anyway handle it in spark to get all the data even though schema are different.